# tree maps using actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, treemaps

can any body help me??
i have a task to make a tree map with actionscript 3.0 and using the rectangle packing algorithm!!!
can anybody help me,,i cant find a resourse to teach me how to do this,,i only know what is a tree map and i know actionscript,,nothingmore
will adobe flex help me in this task??
please i need your help..

Comment: What do you mean by a tree-map? An associative array implemented using a binary search tree? If so, you might want to consider using ActionScript's built-in associative arrays instead.

Comment: this is the tree map what i mean 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping

Comment: Knowing the algorithm and knowing the programming language it should be implemented in is usually sufficient. Can you refine your question? There is an open source tree map implementation for flex: http://code.google.com/p/flex2treemap/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this library can help. [AS3 Data Structures For Game Developers](http://lab.polygonal.de/ds/)